# Fetched sorted API data(NodeJs &Mongoose) not getting displayed in sorted order when try display in Angular UI

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose

I have tried to get sorted in backend & tested via postman and I am getting sorted order.

```
const locationInfo = await locationDetails.find(query).sort({sectionName:1});
res.json(locationInfo);

[
    {    //some other keys &values
        "sectionName": "Closet",
    },
    {
        "sectionName": "Dining",

    },
    {
        "sectionName": "Kitchen",

    },
    {

        "sectionName": "Other",
    },
    {

        "sectionName": "Refrigerator",
    }
]
```

After REST call storing result to,

```
this.result=data;
```

but when I try to display the same resultant data on UI, Its not getting displayed in sorted order as well as checked in console also resultant data order got changed.

**Console Data**

```
[{
sectionName: "Refrigerator",
},
{
sectionName: "Kitchen",
},
{
sectionName: "Dining",
},
{
sectionName: "Closet",
},
{
sectionName: "Other",
}]
```

> Note: Tried to sort from .ts file also but it is not working.

```
this.result.sort(function(a,b){a.sectionName-b.sectionName});
```

If any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`SectioName` is not a valid criterion for MongoDB to sort the return result. In this case, MongoDB does not know how to sort it.

Here is an example directly from the MongoDB documentation about `cursor.sort()`:

```js
db.restaurants.insertMany( [
   { "_id" : 1, "name" : "Central Park Cafe", "borough" : "Manhattan"},
   { "_id" : 2, "name" : "Rock A Feller Bar and Grill", "borough" : "Queens"},
   { "_id" : 3, "name" : "Empire State Pub", "borough" : "Brooklyn"},
   { "_id" : 4, "name" : "Stan's Pizzaria", "borough" : "Manhattan"},
   { "_id" : 5, "name" : "Jane's Deli", "borough" : "Brooklyn"},
] );

# The following command uses the sort() method to sort on the borough field:
db.restaurants.find().sort( { "borough": 1 } )
```

Documents are returned in alphabetical order by borough, but the order of those documents with duplicate values for borough might not be the same across multiple executions.

`.sort` works best with numerical values. If you are in control of the backend and are able to change how data is stored in the database. I suggest you create a field for the creation date or just an index to indicate the order of the items.

Let's say your document looks something like this:

```json
# Doc 1
{
sectionName: "Refrigerator",
order:1
}
# Doc 2
{
sectionName: "Refrigerator",
order:2
}
```

Then you can do

```
const locationInfo = await locationDetails.find(query).sort({order:1});
```

which will return you the documents sorted using the order field, and the order will be consistent.

Comment: ,Thanks for the respone!.
I have created index for sectionName and tried,it is returning data in sorted order only that I have verified via POSTMAN already but when I invoke that REST service from my .ts file only the order of items getting changed.